# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Times Out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Server running Tomcat.

[image]

It was working perfectly on Friday, but I went away for the weekend, and now when I try access it on the Monday morning, it just get a Timeout all the time.

[image]

If I look at the logs for today, there are no errors. The Tomcat Server seems to have started with no errors.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.2017-02-27.log
-------------------------------------
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:41)
27-Feb-2017 08:34:46.093 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-Feb-2017 08:34:46.096 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
27-Feb-2017 08:34:46.126 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-Feb-2017 08:34:46.128 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 19 2016 19:32:05 UTC
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.39.0
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.41-36.55.amzn1.x86_64
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.164 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.29.amzn1.x86_64/jre
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.164 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.164 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.164 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat8
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.164 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.166 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING=
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.166 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DRDS_PORT=3306
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.166 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DRDS_HOSTNAME=aa7ntem7cua781.c1gnuzdz0oma.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.166 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DRDS_USERNAME=admin
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DRDS_DB_NAME=ebdb
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DRDS_PASSWORD=blikkies
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=64m
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.171 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms256m
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.171 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat8
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat8/temp
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.173 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.173 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.557 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.628 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.632 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.635 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.642 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2439 ms
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
27-Feb-2017 08:34:50.787 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
27-Feb-2017 08:35:09.864 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
27-Feb-2017 08:35:10.532 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'rest': initialization started
27-Feb-2017 08:35:10.558 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'rest-servlet': startup date [Mon Feb 27 08:35:10 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
27-Feb-2017 08:35:10.711 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class com.jobs.spring.configuration.AppConfig]
27-Feb-2017 08:35:12.279 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<init> JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
27-Feb-2017 08:35:13.057 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
27-Feb-2017 08:35:13.771 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.1.Final}
27-Feb-2017 08:35:13.782 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
27-Feb-2017 08:35:13.784 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
27-Feb-2017 08:35:13.965 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
27-Feb-2017 08:35:15.041 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.312 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/category/list],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Category>> com.jobs.spring.controller.CategoryRESTService.findAllCategorys()
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.316 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/category/list/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Category> com.jobs.spring.controller.CategoryRESTService.findCategoryById(java.lang.String)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.336 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/list/matching/{firstResult}/{maxResults}/{latitude}/{longitude}/{maxDistance}/{miles}/{jobId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job>> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.findMatchingJobs(int,int,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.Long)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/list/range/{firstResult}/{maxResults}/{type}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job>> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.findAllJobs(int,int,java.lang.Integer)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/list/range/{firstResult}/{maxResults}/{latitude}/{longitude}/{maxDistance}/{miles}/{type}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job>> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.findAllJobs(int,int,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.Integer)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.343 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/list/range/{firstResult}/{maxResults}/{latitude}/{longitude}/{maxDistance}/{miles}/{searchQuery}/{subCategories}/{rating}/{personId}/{favourite}/{type}/{lastOnline}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job>> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.findAllJobs(int,int,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,long,boolean,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Long)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.344 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/list/in/{ids}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job>> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.findJobById(java.lang.String)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.345 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/list/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.findJobById(java.lang.Long)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.346 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/list/person/{personId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job>> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.findJobByPersonId(java.lang.Long)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.354 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/list/person/{personId}/{type}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job>> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.findJobByPersonIdAndType(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Integer)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.355 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/save],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.saveJob(com.jobs.spring.domain.Job)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.357 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/delete],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.deleteJob(com.jobs.spring.domain.Job)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.358 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/job/delete/person],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.JobRESTService.deleteJobForPerson(com.jobs.spring.domain.Person)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.380 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/map/list],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.MapRange>> com.jobs.spring.controller.MapRESTService.findAll()
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.382 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/map/list/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.MapRange> com.jobs.spring.controller.MapRESTService.findById(java.lang.Long)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.389 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/map/delete],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.MapRange> com.jobs.spring.controller.MapRESTService.delete(com.jobs.spring.domain.MapRange)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.393 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/map/save],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.MapRange> com.jobs.spring.controller.MapRESTService.save(com.jobs.spring.domain.MapRange)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.396 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/notification/{deviceToken}/{topics}/{mesage}/{from}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.jobs.spring.controller.NotificationRESTService.push(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.424 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/list/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.findPersonById(java.lang.Long)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.424 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/list/in/{ids}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person>> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.findPersonById(java.lang.String)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.426 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/list/uid/{uid}/provider/{provider}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.findPersonByUidAndProvider(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.427 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/list/uid/{uid}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.findPersonByUid(java.lang.String)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.429 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/list/email/{email}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.findPersonByEmail(java.lang.String)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.430 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/save],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.savePerson(com.jobs.spring.domain.Person)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.431 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/updatetime],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.updateTimeStamps(com.jobs.spring.domain.Person)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.432 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/list/favouritejob/{id}/{type}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Set<com.jobs.spring.domain.Job>> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.findFavoriuteJobsByPersonId(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Integer)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.437 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/list/isfavouritejob/{personId}/{jobId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Boolean> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.isFavoriuteJob(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.438 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/list/range/{firstResult}/{maxResults}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person>> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.findAllPersons(int,int)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.439 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/list],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person>> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.findAllPersons()
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.439 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/save/favouritejob/{id}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.saveFavoriuteJobByPersonId(java.lang.Long,com.jobs.spring.domain.Job)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.440 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/remove/favouritejob/{id}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.removeFavoriuteJobByPersonId(java.lang.Long,com.jobs.spring.domain.Job)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.442 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/person/delete],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Person> com.jobs.spring.controller.PersonRESTService.deletePerson(com.jobs.spring.domain.Person)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.453 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/rating/list/range/{firstResult}/{maxResults}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Rating>> com.jobs.spring.controller.RatingRESTService.findAllRatings(int,int)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.455 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/rating/list],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Rating>> com.jobs.spring.controller.RatingRESTService.findAllRatings()
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.455 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/rating/list/range/{firstResult}/{maxResults}/{jobId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.Rating>> com.jobs.spring.controller.RatingRESTService.findAllRatings(int,int,java.lang.Long)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.456 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/rating/list/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Rating> com.jobs.spring.controller.RatingRESTService.findRatingById(java.lang.Long)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.457 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/rating/save],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.Rating> com.jobs.spring.controller.RatingRESTService.saveRating(com.jobs.spring.domain.Rating)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.463 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/subcategory/list/{categoryId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.SubCategory>> com.jobs.spring.controller.SubCategoryRESTService.findAllCategorys(java.lang.String)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.465 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/subcategory/list],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.jobs.spring.domain.SubCategory>> com.jobs.spring.controller.SubCategoryRESTService.findAllCategorys()
27-Feb-2017 08:35:33.466 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/subcategory/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.jobs.spring.domain.SubCategory> com.jobs.spring.controller.SubCategoryRESTService.findCategoryById(java.lang.String)
27-Feb-2017 08:35:34.314 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'rest-servlet': startup date [Mon Feb 27 08:35:10 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
27-Feb-2017 08:35:34.712 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'rest': initialization completed in 24180 ms
27-Feb-2017 08:35:34.762 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 43,970 ms
27-Feb-2017 08:35:34.798 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-Feb-2017 08:35:34.818 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
27-Feb-2017 08:35:34.820 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 44177 ms
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check your tomcat logs whether your request is coming to the server or not?

Comment: The last time the logs (specifically `localhost_access_log.txt`) show it was accessed was 23 Feb (27 Feb Today). e.g. `127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2017:14:49:50 +0000] "GET /map/list HTTP/1.1" 200 306`

Comment: I have checked all the logs (last 100 lines), and there is no sign of me accessing the server. This is strange because a server reboot looks fine and registers all the end points as you can see above. Notably, the `elasticbeanstalk-access_log` last entry was 23 Feb.

Comment: I cannot post questions on Amazons AWS forums, guess it's because I am only using their free tier. How are you supposed to trial their free tier with these restrictions?  Should I look at another service like OpenShift rather?

Comment: are you hitting the right URL then? I think you have to make sure your web-server is exposed

Comment: Yes. I even click the link provided by AWS (see image in the description  above). How do you expose the Web server? Ps. Nothing has changed since when it was previously working.